# What is 'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader();' and in which situations is it used?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, request-headers

I stumbled on this command while learning AJAX. The guy who made the tutorial didn't explain this command, what do the parameters inside the command mean and what is it used for... Below is the code I used it in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function insert(){
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            };

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                };  
            };

            parameters = 'insert_text='+document.getElementById('insert_text').value;

            xmlhttp.open('POST','ajax_posting_data.php',true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send(parameters);
        };

    </script>
```

Comment: The doc is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method

Comment: @talnicolas: It's pretty useless to send a guy some dry formal document from W3.org as a way of explaining the meaning and purpose of some procedure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HTTP is a protocol.  Part of that protocol is the concept of request headers.   When an xhr happens, text is exchanged between the client and server.  Request headers are part of the text that the client sends to the server.

This is a way to set the request headers.  The arguments you see are

1) the header to set  (in this case, **Content-type**)
2) the header value. (in this case, **x-www-form-urlencoded**)

[See this for more info.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: I know what requestHeaders are, but I indeed found this example useful when I needed to plugin request headers on an app that didn't have jQuery.

Answer (score 9):

HTTP requests are messages passed from one computer system to another according to a set routine (a 'protocol' - here **H**yper**T**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol) in order to do things like send data, ask for data to be sent back, update data previously sent, etc.

A header is basically a piece of information about the data in the body of the HTTP request. Its purpose is to tell the machine receiving the request what type of data is enclosed in the body of the request, its formatting, the language used, if it's to set a cookie, the date, the host machine, etc.

More than one header can be put on a HTTP request and each header has a 'name' and a 'value' component. On web pages they look like

```
<meta name="........" content="............."/>
```

and you find them just below the top of the web page within the  element.

To enable people to send HTTP requests from within a JavaScript function, we create a new XMLHttpRequest object, just as your code does so with

```
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

To this new empty object you intend to add data. Despite its name, XMLHttpRequest also allows sending data in a number of formats other than XML, e.g. HTML code, text, JSON, etc. In your example each data name will be separated from its value by an "=" character and each data/value pairing will be separated from the next pairing by an "&" character. This kind of formatting is known as URL encoding.

We have to tell the receiving computer how the data within the HTTP request body is encoded. There is a [standard header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields) to convey this and it is added to the request via the method **setRequestHeader(..)**. This method uses 2 parameters, the header name and the header's value. All this operation is achieved in the line

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

This **setRequestHeader(..)** method must be applied to the request **after** the request is characterized with the **open(...)** method but **before** the final request is sent off with the **send(.)** method.

The **open(...)** method defines: (1) the type of HTTP request, e.g. GET/POST/PUT etc; (2) the web page that contains the handling script for this request, e.g. some .php file or Node.js request endpoint that makes the appropriate query to the back end database; and (3) the nature of the request dynamics, e.g. asynchronous requests are assigned a value 'true', synchronous requests are assigned 'false'.

The **send(.)** method attaches the data to be sent within the body of the request, in your case the variable called 'parameters'.

On your broader question of which situations **setRequestHeader(..)** is used, I would say that it is used in most HTTP request situations. But [some types of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802133/send-xmlhttprequest-with-both-header-and-formdata/23814349#23814349) added to the body of a HTTP request invoke a default setting for the 'Content-Type' header.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly what it says. It will set a "header" information for the next `XMLHttpRequest`.

A header is pretty much a key/value pair. It is used to transmit "meta" information to the target server for the ongoing request. In your particular instance, its used to tell the server which content type is used for this request.

Comment: This answer is of value only if the poster already knows clearly what XHRs, headers and meta-information are. But if they had these concepts down, they'd hardly ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sets the Content-type HTTP header to contain url encoded data sent from a form.